# Spring-Cloud-dataflow without Streams component

Tags: spring-batch, kubernetes-helm, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm setting up new spring-cloud-dataflow in Kubernetes cluster with helm. I want to make use of spring-cloud-dataflow only for Jobs and Task without streams component (i.e) without any messaging broker component. Is it possible to achieve this ?

My use case of spring-cloud-dataflow is to manage jobs and view the status of execution, similar to spring-batch-admin

**Edit:** Managed to install spring-cloud-dataflow with helm but getting below error when trying to connect to external mysql

**Datasource configuration:**
      datasource:
        **url:** 'jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/dataflow'
        **driverClassName**: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        **username**: root
        **password**: password

java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.1' (using password: NO)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:232)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:165)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1128)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:560)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:174)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:92)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5bde5f2.getConnection()
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)

**Update: Solved Should use mysql 5.7 version**

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to achieve this ?

yes, that's possible. You can use SCDF only for tasks (no messaging apps) as a replacement for the deprecated Spring Batch Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any reference on how to achieve this with helm charts ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Hi, I was able to install Spring cloud data flow without skipper, streams and with external mysql database. Getting the below error while connecting with shell.Unable to contact Data Flow Server at 'http://localhost:80': 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deployments relation is required'.